# how data types are processed by Compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, types

I struggle to understand how data types are processeed by compiler like C++. 
When entering anything from keyboard let say number 123, we see that same number on screen but depending upon the data types it is stored differently. What is the algorithm that goes behind converting the data types even though that same keyboard strokes are entered? How come numbers are stored differently and displayed differently? for instance in above case if number 123 is an int type it will be stored as 01111011 (in 1 byte) however if it is string type it will be stored in 3 bytes (one byte for each number). But in both cases we see the same number on the screen. Does computer use different bytes to store and display numbers?
My question is when we enter any number does it go through the ASCII table and look up the char code of that number and then the compiler does some sort of processing to store that number in appropriate data type and diplay that number?

Thanks heaps

Comment: Maybe you just need to read a book on compiling. Your question is too broad to answer here IMO.

Comment: leppie thanks for your suggesstion. I would be grateful if you can point me to any website or article.

Comment: @user2031427 take a look at ANTLR.org, it is a tool to create compilers which has a GUI. This will increase your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You will really want to get a book on compilers to answer this questions properly, but specifically for numbers strings you would do this during the lexical analysis phase of the compilation.

The compiler scans through the text of the program and attempts to form tokens, these would be basic building blocks of the syntax, so a string, {, number, etc...

So lets say you get something like this

`int i = 10`

You compiler scans through this line and attempts to create the tokens. First it scans i, n, t, then when it gets to space it stops, since it would treat space as a delimeter. It checks the value "int" against it's internal list and generates the appropriate token.

It continues through the string and detects the variable i, an equals sign, and then a number.

The way it tells the number from the string "10" is probably the quotation marks, but this would depend on the language.

this is why you have things like 10L or 10f to indicate that you are creating a long or float value. Otherwise the compiler could not tell.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Compiler_construction

or perhaps even https://www.coursera.org/course/compilers

Comment: Thanks AnthonyM. I went through those websites but still couldnt find the answer.